# Objective C - UIStepper reaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I tried to ask this question, but somehow I failed to express myself right I guess so I deleted it and started fresh.

I have a hierarchy:- **ViewController** => **UIView** => **Stepper**

Here is  my code of the UIView:-

```
@implementation Controls
@synthesize m_numColumn=_whatever;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        int i;
        m_numColumn= [[UIStepper alloc]init];
        m_numColumn.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, 30, 30);
        m_numColumn.autorepeat= FALSE;
        [m_numColumn setValue:2];
        m_displayColumnNum= [[UILabel alloc]init];
        m_displayColumnNum.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 60, 30);
      //  m_displayColumnNum.backgroundColor =lgammaf(<#float#>);
       // m_displayColumnNum.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"aaaaaa"];
        i= m_numColumn.value;
        m_displayColumnNum.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [self addSubview:m_numColumn];
        [self addSubview:m_displayColumnNum];
     //   Controls.delegate = [m_numColumn.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [m_numColumn addTarget:self  action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[m_numColumn setdelegate];


    }
    return self;
}
```

The important line here is:

```
[m_numColumn addTarget:self  action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What I would like is to react on that event in the UIViewController (parent object). How do I do that?

Comment: As an aside - lose the Hungarian notation, it looks really odd to an Objective-C developer. There is a short and useful [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1) on the Apple developer site that is worth reading.

Comment: Too early for me... Im currently learning the basics...
However... when i grow more experienced i will look into it.

Comment: Learning to write readable code is basics. It helps you to read the code that others with more experience write as well. But, it's your choice.

Comment: Good point. I should reconsider...

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem that you don't get the event? I have always used UIStepper with "UIControlEventValueChanged", in your case it should be:

```
[m_numColumn addTarget:self  action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Im pretty new and just learning so plz be slow on me :P
I get the event within controls object but i would like to get it somehow in the Parent Ojbrect (ViewController)
i think thats what delegates are for but i dont know...

Comment: You should add the view controller as target: 
 `[m_numColumn addTarget:parentViewController action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Comment: Sorry my poste was a little short... im aware that the Target is wrong but i dont know how to do it right... by using "parentViewController" it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

there is the point of the controlEvents you are listening to, but there is also a problem with the target

```
[m_numColumn addTarget:self  action:@selector(stepperChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you shouldn't use "self" which is a reference to your view and not your view controller, either use a "myController" variable or do this method inside your controller

Comment: I know that much. I just don't know how do that how to point it on my viewController. I implemented the method in ViewController but i dont know how to call it. i guess i have to give the controller somehow a pointer of it (whats called here a delegate i guess)